# Why do I need to use andThen in order to pattern match Futures?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, future

I found out that in order to pattern match `Future` fur `Success`/`Failure`, I need to use `andThen` (or `onComplete`, `onSuccess`...) and cannot use `map`. Why is that?

What I wanted to do (simplified, I am matching for `Success` and so on as well):

```
val f1 = Future(throw new Exception("Oops"))
f1 map { case Failure(e) => ??? }
```

Gives:

```
error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.util.Failure[T]
 required: Nothing
       f1 map { case Failure(e) => ??? }
```

What I ended up doing:

```
val f1 = Future(throw new Exception("Oops"))
f1 andThen { case Failure(e) => ??? }
```

I would like to understand why `map` cannot be used here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the signature of `map`: it takes a `A => B` and returns a `Future[B]`. If you will, you can look at a `Future` as follows:

```
type Future[A] = Async[Either[Throwable, A]]
```

`Future#map`, `Future#flatMap` and `Future.apply` view this "stack" of types as a single big thing with a hole (`Future` is basically a special cased monad transformer). When you `map`/`flatMap` on a `Future`, you are only operating on the inner `A`.

Comment: So you mean that I would be only operating on the `Exception` itself and the rest (`Future` and `Future#Failure`) is "flatten", correct?

Comment: The other way around: with `map` you only operate on `A`. To be able to act on the `Exception` you need other operators like `recover` or `transform`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Comment: This is really helpful answer for slightly touching the "Monad Transformer" concept.

Answer (score 2):

Because the type signature isn't correct. When you want to map over a `Future[A]`, you need to provide a function taking an `A` and producing a `B`, which isn't what you seem to be doing. What you're looking for is `recover`:

```
f1 recover { case e => // e is already a `Throwable` here ??? }
```

Comment: I'm aware of `recover` as well. Does it makes sense (i.e. not a bad practice) to use `andThen` to handle both `Success` and `Failure`, instead of `map` and then `recover`?

Comment: @BobDem I'd say `map` and `recover` are more idiomatic. Note that comment on `andThen`:  *"Note that if one of the chained `andThen` callbacks throwsan exception, that exception is not propagated to the subsequent `andThen` callbacks. Instead, the subsequent `andThen` callbacks are given the original value of this future."*

Comment: That's a very clear drawback, even though it looks much cleaner (to me) and I'd have loved to use it for everything. Is it so then that it's general practice to wrap `Future`s with `map` to operate on success and `recover` for failures?

Comment: @BobDem Yes, it is a general practice I use in most places where I use `Future`.